# How to add additional headers along with value in wso2 api manger?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am trying setting up wso2 api manager  and trying to add additional header parameter with values from wso2 manager
Is there any way to do, have installed only  wso2 api manager,

Comment: Hi Joel, yes you can add additional headers to send to the backend. You can simply add the headers via a custom in sequence or even using a custom handler. The easiest option is to use custom in sequence. Follow https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+Mediation+Extensions

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sequence like below and update in the insequence of the mediation when publishing the api.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="sequence">  
 <property name="Test" value="Test1" scope="transport"/>
</sequence>
```

or you can use the header mediator. Refer [this blog](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Header+Mediator).

Also you can place the sequence in the API file.